# PowerShell: best way to escape double quotes in string passed to an external program? E.g., a JSON string

Tags: json, powershell

I read I think all the articles on escaping strings in PowerShell, but I still haven't found the solution that would satisfy me.

Suppose I have a file `foo.json` that contains a JSON string. I need to pass the JSON string to a program as an argument.

In bash, this works just fine:

`myprogram "$(cat ~/foo.json)"`

In PowerShell, when I read the contents of the file normally and pass it in, the receiving program complains about there not being quotes around the keys and the values.

What I've come up with is:

`$json = (get-content ~/foo.json | Out-String) -replace '"','""'
myprogram $json`

Is there a less awkward way to do this in PowerShell? I've resorted to exiting the session, running the command in bash, then starting the session again.

Comment: In json files, all keys and values are quoted, except for numeric values. If the json file you want to pass as a string contains these quote characters, they will not be altered if you read it in with `myprogram (Get-Content foo.json -Raw)`

Comment: @Theo: The problem here is PowerShell's (lack of) quoting when passing a string with embedded `"` chars.  to an _external program_.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, **PowerShell's passing of arguments with embedded double quotes to *external programs* is broken up to *PowerShell 7.2.x***, requiring you to ***manually* `\`-escape** them as `\"`:

- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55604316/45375) for more information about the underlying problem.

---

A **robust workaround** requires not only replacing all `"` with `\"`, but also doubling any `\` immediately preceding them.

```bash
# Note: If your JSON has no embedded *escaped* double quotes
#       - \" - you can get away with: -replace '"', '\"'
myprogram ((Get-Content -Raw ~/foo.json) -replace '(\\*)"', '$1$1\"')
```

<sup>Note the use of `Get-Content -Raw`, which is preferable to `Get-Content ... | Out-String` for reading the entire file into a *single*, multi-line string, but note that it requires PSv3+.</sup>

---

*Assuming that your JSON contains either no escape sequences at all or only instances of `\"`*, a simpler workaround, discovered by [Vivere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14183155/vivere), is to encode the JSON strings as JSON *again*, via [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json):

```bash
# Works, but only if your JSON contains no escape sequences
# such as \n or \\
myprogram (Get-Content -Raw ~/foo.json | ConvertTo-Json)
```

Comment: Also, is there a reason to prefer \" to ""?

Comment: Glad to hear it, @TatianaRacheva. You may prefer `\`"` for consistency, given that `\`` is the general escape character, but `""` works fine inside `"..."`; note that inside `'...'`, `''` is the only way to embed single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I´ve replaced all double quotes by single quote before call the parameter, and set double quote just in the beggining and in the end. Worked like a charm in Powershell Script.

In my scenario, I was calling Powershell from groovy.

changeorderParam is where I have my Json string.

```
changeorderParam = changeorderParam.replaceAll("\"", "'")
bat "powershell.exe -Executionpolicy bypass -file C:\\\scripts\\\script.ps1 \\\"${template}\\\" \\"${script}\\" \\"${branch}\\" \\"${changeorderParam}\\""
```

I hope this help someone!