# How to pass JSON (string data) to PowerShell?

Tags: json, powershell, batch-file, syntax, quoting

I'm passing the following as an argument to powershell (v4 on w7):

```
-debugWrite -fileName SettingsFile -jsonContent { "c": "some setting", "d":  "unknown", "b": "some thing", "a": 1 }
```

But PS gets hung up on the JSON. I've tried delimiting the \double-quotes\ and putting everything after -jsonContent in 'single quotes', but to no avail.

Here is the Windows 7 (PS4) environment PS is running in:

*note: "..." obfuscation refers to the same dir. IOW, all files live in the same directory.*

A batch file is run, kicking off the whole thing:

```
    "C:\...\script.bat" > "C:\...\script-output.txt" 2>&1
```

This runs `script.bat` and outputs to `script-output.txt`. `script.bat` is a long 1-liner:

```
%WINDIR%\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\...\customscript.PS1" --% -fileName DropFileToCreate -jsonContent "{     "c":  "some setting",     "d":  "unknown",     "b":  "some thing",     "a":  1 }" -debugWrite
```

Legend:

`DropFileToCreate` - the filename passed to the PS script, used to create a file in same dir.

`-jsonContent` - A named parameter in the script (see below for header of `customscript.PS1`)

In the above example, the JSON is:

> "{     "c":  "some setting",     "d":  "unknown",     "b":  "some
>   thing",     "a":  1 }"

`-debugWrite` - A switch parameter (used here to enable Write-Host debugging)

Finally, a bit of the `customscript.PS1`:

```
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    [String]
    $fileName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    $jsonContent,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)]
    [Switch]
    $debugWrite = $False
)
[...]
```

The JSON is easier seen, and spaces explained, if expressed as:

```
{
 "c": "some setting",
 "d": "unknown",
 "b": "some thing",
 "a": 1 
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Your overall `"..."`-enclosed JSON string has *embedded* `"`, which must be escaped as `\"` (sic; command simplified):

```sh
powershell.exe -File "C:\...\customscript.PS1" ... -jsonContent "{ \"c\": \"some setting\", \"d\": \"unknown\", \"b\": \"some thing\", \"a\": 1 }"
```

Read on for when additional escaping is needed, how `-File` invocation differs from `-Command` invocation, and in what way the calling shell (where you call `powershell.exe` from) matters.

---

Note:

- This answer primarily discusses use of the  *Windows PowerShell* executable, `powershell.exe`, but it applies analogously to the PowerShell *Core* executable, `pwsh`, and there's a section on calling from `bash` at the bottom.
- The section *Calling from PowerShell itself* below, specifically the syntax required with `-File`, applies to passing JSON to other programs such as `curl.exe` as well.

The required **syntax for the PowerShell CLI** - that is, invoking `powershell.exe` with arguments - **depends on**:

- whether you're calling from `cmd.exe` (Command Prompt / batch file) or from PowerShell itself (or, in PowerShell *Core* from a POSIX-like shell such as `bash`).
- whether you pass arguments to `powershell -Command` (inline command) or 
  `powerShell -File` (script path).

Either way, your original attempt could not have worked, because literal **`{ "c": "some setting" ... }` cannot be recognized as a *single argument***, due to **containing whitespace** and **not being enclosed in quotes** overall; the command added later, with enclosing `"..."`, lacks escaping of the embedded `"`.

The following commands demonstrate the required syntax for the scenarios discussed, using a simplified JSON string.

To make the `-File` commands runnable, create a `script.ps1` file in the current dir. with the following content: `ConvertFrom-Json $Args[0]`

---

#### Calling from `cmd.exe` / a batch file

- Embedded `"` must be escaped as `\"` (even though PowerShell-*internally* you'd use `` `" ``).
- **Important:**

  - **If the JSON text contains `cmd.exe` *metacharacters*** (invariably between `\"...\"` runs), you must **`^`-escape them individually**, because `cmd.exe`, due to not recognizing `\"` as an escaped `"`, considers these substrings *unquoted*; e.g., `\"some & setting\"` must be escaped as `\"some ^& setting\"`; the `cmd.exe` metacharacters that need escaping here are:
    `& | < > ^`
- **`cmd.exe`-style environment-variable references** such as `%USERNAME%` ***are* interpolated** - `cmd.exe` has no *literal* string syntax, it only recognizes `"..."`, where interpolation *does* take place, just as in *unquoted* tokens.
  If you want to pass such a token as-is, i.e., to *suppress* interpolation, the escaping syntax depends on whether you're calling from the *command line* or a *batch file*, sadly: use `%^USERNAME%` from the former, and `%%USERNAME%%` from the latter - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420292/45375) for the gory details.
- Note how the `-Command` calls simply add another layer of quoting, by enclosing the `"..."` string in `'...'`. This is required, because with `-Command` PowerShell treats the arguments it receives as PowerShell *source code* rather than as *literal arguments* (the latter is what happens with `-File`); if it weren't for the enclosing `'...'`, the overall enclosing `"..."` would be *stripped* before interpretation.

**With `-File`**:

```sh
# With a literal string:
powershell -File ./script.ps1 "{ \"c\": \"some setting\", \"unknown\": \"b\" }"

# With an expandable string (expanded by the caller):
powershell -File ./script.ps1 "{ \"c\": \"some %USERNAME%\", \"unknown\": \"b\" }"
```

**With `-Command`**:

```sh
# With a literal string:
powershell -Command ConvertFrom-Json '"{ \"c\": \"some setting\", \"unknown\": \"b\" }"'

# With an expandable string (expanded by the caller):
powershell -Command ConvertFrom-Json '"{ \"c\": \"some %USERNAME%\", \"unknown\": \"b\" }"'
```

---

#### Calling from PowerShell itself

- Calling from PowerShell makes the need to escape `cmd.exe` metacharacters go away, because `cmd.exe` is not involved.
- PowerShell's string-quoting rules apply, which simplifies matters, although, sadly, **you still need to manually `\`-escape embedded `"` chars.**; see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/2361) for background.

  - *Update*: PowerShell Core 7.2.0-preview.5 introduced an [experimental feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Experimental_Features), `PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing`, which obviates the need for this manual `\`-escaping; even though it is very much to be hoped for in this case, experimental features aren't guaranteed to become regular features; as of PowerShell Core 7.2.0-preview.5, the feature is a step in the right direction, but is both buggy and lacks important accommodations for CLIs on Windows - see [GitHub issue #15143](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15143).
  - Using outer `'...'` quoting simplifies the syntax for the embedded quoting, but that limits you to passing *literal* strings.
  - Using outer `"..."` allows you to embed variable references and expressions from the caller (which are expanded by the *caller*, *before* the argument is passed), but it complicates the syntax, given that an embedded `"` must then be *doubly* escaped as `` \`" `` (sic): first with `` ` `` to conform to PowerShell-*internal* syntax, then with `\` to satisfy the PowerShell *CLI*'s requirements.
  - If your JSON text is not a literal and stored in a *variable*, you must pass 
    `$jsonVar -replace '"', '\"'` to perform the necessary escaping - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52823647/45375).

**With `-File` or when calling *external programs* such as `curl.exe`**:

```sh
# With a literal string:
powershell -File ./script.ps1 '{ \"c\": \"some setting\", \"unknown\": \"b\" }'

# With an expandable string (expanded by the caller):
powershell -File ./script.ps1 "{ \`"c\`": \`"some $env:OS\`", \`"unknown\`": \`"b\`" }"
```

**With `-Command`**:

```sh
# With a literal string:
powershell -Command ConvertFrom-Json '''"{ \"c\": \"some setting\", \"unknown\": \"b\" }"'''

# With an expandable string (expanded by the caller):
powershell -Command ConvertFrom-Json "'{ \`"c\`": \`"some $env:OS\`", \`"unknown\`": \`"b\`" }'"
```

---

#### PowerShell *Core*: Calling from `bash`

- Bash, like PowerShell, understands both expanding (interpolating) `"..."` strings and literal `'...'` strings.
- Bash, unlike `cmd.exe`, recognizes `\"` as escaped `"` chars. inside `"..."`, so there's no need to escape any of Bash's metacharacters.

**With `-File`**:

```sh
# With a literal string:
pwsh -File ./script.ps1 '{ "c": "some setting", "unknown": "b" }'

# With an expandable string (expanded by the caller):
pwsh -File ./script.ps1 "{ \"c\": \"some $USER\", \"unknown\": \"b\" }"
```

**With `-Command`**:

```sh
# With a literal string:
pwsh -Command ConvertFrom-Json \''{ "c": "some setting", "unknown": "b" }'\'

# With an expandable string (expanded by the caller):
pwsh -Command ConvertFrom-Json "'{ \"c\": \"some $USER\", \"unknown\": \"b\" }'"
```

Comment: I can't believe it's been 5 years, and this is till a way-cool trick! :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a variable to pass the string.  For the example JSON given, it avoids escaping entirely.  `ConvertFrom-Json` can be used as a test app.

First in PowerShell, observe

```
PS C:\> $psJson = '{ "c": "some setting", "d": "unknown", "b": "some thing", "a": 1 }'
PS C:\> ConvertFrom-Json $psJson

c            d       b          a
-            -       -          -
some setting unknown some thing 1
```

From CMD, we can achieve the same result.  When PowerShell is opened from a batch, it inherits the environment.  Instead of passing the string, set an environment variable and use it like a global

```
C:\>set dosJson={ "c": "some setting", "d": "unknown", "b": "some thing", "a": 1 }

C:\>powershell -command "& { ConvertFrom-Json $env:dosJson }"

c            d       b          a
-            -       -          -
some setting unknown some thing 1
```

**EDIT:**

It should be pointed out that this works for `-Command` and not `-File`, because the PowerShell environment is not available to the `-File` args.  Of course you can run a script inside a `-Command`.  Using a trivial test script `test.ps1`

```
C:\>type test.ps1
param ([string] $json)
ConvertFrom-Json $json
C:\>powershell -command "& { C:\test.ps1 $env:dosJson }"

c            d       b          a
-            -       -          -
some setting unknown some thing 1
```

So the `script.bat` in the question would have to be changed to `-Command`.

Comment: Nicely done; another option would be to pass JSON via _stdin_ (the pipeline), but the target script would have to be designed for that. As an aside: There's no reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.