# How can I pass an argument that may contain quotes and non-ASCII characters from PowerShell to an external program?

Tags: bash, powershell, quoting

I want to pass from a PowerShell script to an external (CygWin) program arguments (file paths), which contain arbitrary characters, including single quotes, double quotes, backslashes, spaces, and non-ASCII characters.  Through some obscure ways, single and double quotes go missing and the [recommended quoting mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822984/powershell-best-way-to-escape-double-quotes-in-string-passed-to-an-external-pro) isn't enough to fix the problem.  Specifically, double quotes at the beginning of the string get replaced by a backslash, single quotes at the beginning or end of the string get lost, and single quotes interfere with non-ASCII characters in unpredictable ways.

As an example, consider this `echo-first.sh` *sh* shell script, which echoes its first argument.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
echo "$1"
```

Here is the output of *Windows PowerShell* (5.1) when I run the script with various arguments, each prefixed with a comment indicating whether the output is correct or not.

```
# OK: hello world
bash ./echo-first.sh "hello world"

# Not OK: double
bash ./echo-first.sh 'double " quote'

# Not OK: double quoted
bash ./echo-first.sh '"double quoted"'

# OK: double " quote
bash ./echo-first.sh ('double " quote' -replace  '"', '\"')

# Not OK: \double quoted"
bash ./echo-first.sh ('"double quoted"' -replace  '"', '\"')

# OK: A "double quoted" phrase
bash ./echo-first.sh ('A "double quoted" phrase' -replace  '"', '\"')

# OK: single ' quote
bash ./echo-first.sh "single ' quote"

# OK: 'single quoted'
bash ./echo-first.sh "'single quoted'"

# Not OK: [no output]
bash ./echo-first.sh "'"

# Not OK: [no output]
bash ./echo-first.sh "''"

# OK: ''
Write-Output "''"

# OK: αβ''γ
bash ./echo-first.sh "αβ''γ"

# Not OK: αβγδ
bash ./echo-first.sh "αβγ''δ"

# OK: αβγδεζηθικλμ
bash ./echo-first.sh "αβγδεζηθικλμ"

# Not OK: αβγδεζηθικλμ#
bash ./echo-first.sh "αβ''γδεζηθικλμ"

# Major  Minor  Build  Revision
# -----  -----  -----  --------
# 5      1      18362  145
Write-Output $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
```